# How do Word 2010 captions work?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to insert caption next to images in a document and I can't make sense of numbering.

For example the numbers of the illustrations go like this: 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6 when I list the images from the start of the document to the end.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you need to update the fields? Try this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all data in the document
2. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all fields

Hopefully the automatically generated numbers are now in the correct order.

Comment: Damn, I just wasted like two hours googling why my caption numbring for my last table starts over instead of continuing and NO solution worked for me... Finally I just relaunched MS Word and it worked... Remember to always start by this :-/ ... Also, numbering bugs and stuff will increase as long as the report gets bigger, so dont panic xD

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [Dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-a-caption-to-a-graphic-in-a-word-2010-d.html)

1. **Click the graphic**.
   The graphic becomes selected.

[image: IMAGE1]

2. **From the References tab’s Captions group, click the Insert Caption button.**
   A caption frame is placed below the graphic, and the Captions dialog box appears.
3. **In the Caption text box, type the figure caption text.**
   You can remove any text that’s already there.

[image: IMAGE2]

4. **Select a position for the caption from the Position drop-down list.**
   The caption position is relative to the figure.
5. **Click the OK button.**
   The dialog box closes, and the caption is applied to the figure.
6. **If you want to change the caption, simply click the mouse in the caption text box and type a new caption.**

Click anywhere outside the text box when you're done.

7. **To remove a caption, click the caption text box once to select it, and then press the Delete key.**

The caption disappears.

Remember: *The caption itself is a special type of text box, which is like a graphic image but contains text. It’s not grouped with the image, so if you move or resize the image, you have to move or resize the caption box, as well.*

Comment: Interesting reference information, but it does not answer my question. I already know how to insert captions. My problem is that I cannot determine how it generates the number. You see the `1` in `Figure 1`? Well in my case after I add several figures, the figure 2 becomes figure 5 for no reason at all (I didn't change it manually in any way), figure 3 becomes figure 2 and the numbers keep changing as I add more figures.

Comment: So right now I need to add captions and then by hand edit the figure numbers and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Could it be that Figure 1 appears earlier in the text than Figure 5?  Or that it was added first?

Comment: I'm still struggling to rewrite this question so that it can be understandable... Basically, let's say that I have 5 pictures, which I'll name 1 to 5. I insert them so when they are counted from the first page of the document toward the last page, the name of the image matches its number, that is to say picture `1` is the first picture, picture `2` is the second and so on.

Comment: Then I start to add captions by first adding caption to image `1`, then to image `2` and so on. At first, the caption says `image 1` for image `1` and image `2` for image `2`, but as I keep adding captions, the caption of image `2` changes to another number. Unfortunately, I don't have an idea how to explain this better. If you still don't understand what I'm saying, please let me know.